# Using master database instead of specific database

Tags: sql, sql-server

What are the disadvantages of using master database in MSSMS when querying?

One of the manager here was running his query using master database and it took 56mins to finish but when we ran it directly to the database (sdbfile.dbo.) it only took 32 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Usually users have public role to connect to master database, The disadvantage is SQL have to delegate again after authentication to specific database which is referred in query.

Comment: my question is why is it faster when using specific database instead of using master db.

Comment: like I said, SQL have to delegate to specific database after connecting with master database whereby if default db is not master it doesnt need that delegation.

Comment: Refer here than https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180770(v=sql.105).aspx